# Getting unique elements from a container [c++]

Tags: c++, boost, unique

I was looking to get only the unique elements from a container. Let's say `srcContainer` is the container from which I want unique elements. I looked at three options:

1. Using std::unique

   ```
      std::sort(srcContainer.begin(), srcContainer.end());
      srcContainer.erase(std::unique(srcContainer.begin(), srcContainer.end()), srcContainer.end());
   ```
2. Using BOOST::unique

   ```
   boost::erase(srcContainer, boost::unique<boost::return_found_end>(boost::sort(srcContainer)));
   ```
3. My own method

   ```
   std::set<T> uniqueElems(srcContainer.begin(), srcContainer.end());  
   srcContainer.clear();  
   srcContainer.insert(srcContainer.end(), uniqueElems.begin(), uniqueElems.end());
   ```

The issue with 1. and 2. are that they change the order in which members occurred in the original srcContainer. With 3. there is no change in order, and in addition it gives a much better performance compared to 1. and 2 (Is it because there is no explicit sorting in 3. ??) above. The elapsed wall clock time for 3 methods above and the number of elements in srcContainer are given below:

1. size of srcContainer (contains integers) = 1e+6
       - std::unique =   **1.04779 secs**
       - BOOST::unique = **1.04774 secs**
       - Own method =    **0.481638 secs**
2. size of srcContainer (contains integers) = 1e+8
       - std::unique =   **151.554 secs**
       - BOOST::unique = **151.474 secs**
       - Own method =    **57.5693 secs**

My question is:

1. Is there better way to find unique using std::unique or BOOST::unique or any other code and maintaining the original order in the container?
2. Any issue with using method 3. above.

For performance profiling `srcContainer` was created as follows:

```
std::vector<int> srcContainer;  
int halfWay = numElems/2;  
for (size_t k=0; k<numElems; ++k) {  
   if (k < halfWay)  
      srcContainer.push_back(k);  
   else  
      srcContainer.push_back(k - halfWay);  
}
```

*Edits:

Agreed with comments that method 3. also changes the order of elements. Is there a better way to get unique elements without changing order?*

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of srcContainer?

Comment: In this case I used a vector for srcContainer to test. But I want the code to work on most container types like BOOST::unique does.

Comment: I'm just interested: how large are the containers? Did you profile the code, where are the bottlenecks? What platform are you using? Judging from the extreme long execution times, I think that the bottlenecks are in the creation of copies of large containers coming from std::unique and not from the sort.

Comment: You can profile the code with 'valgrind --tool=kcachegrind' after you compile it in debug mode (g++ -g) with no optimization turned on. Then you can use kcachegrind to find the bottlenecks.

Comment: Thanks. The run time listed is only for the portion of code shown. Time taken for creating srcContainer are not included. The size of srcContainer is listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT based on info about source data:
The reason you're seeing the set insertion complete faster than sorting the vector is that your input data is two already sorted ranges. For quicksort (typically used by `std::sort`) this is a degenerate case and one of the worst possible inputs you could give it. For an input size of `1e8` changing the sort from `std::sort` to `std::stable_sort` cut the runtime from ~25s to <9s.

If you want to keep the original item order, you could try something like the following which keeps a hash of all the items. I have *no idea* what the performance of this would be, but for example you could utilize an approach with hashing and `remove_if` as sketched below:

```
struct Remover
{
    explicit Remover(hash& found_items) : found_items_(found_items) { }
    bool operator()(const Iter& item) { retval = <does exist in hash>; add to hash; return retval; }

    hash& found_items_;
};

hash dup_finder;
Remover remover(dup_finder);
std::erase(std::remove_if(src.begin(), src.end(), remover), src.end());
```

Original components of my answer:

If the elements in the source container are already mostly sorted, you may see better performance with `stable_sort` rather than sort prior to calling `unique`. I'm unable to guess without more information about yoru data set what might cause option 3 to perform better than 1&2.

Option 3 should remove uniques but keep in mind that in spite of what you assert, it *will still* reorder the items in exactly the same way that the first two options do.

Comment: Agreed. Using set also sorts the srcContainer and results in order being lost. Is there a way to retain original order and do better?